# vuetify pagination add custom features (slot/template)

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I'm using the VueJS [Vuetify framework](https://vuetifyjs.com/) and I need a pagination option with more features then the basic one available.

what am i looking for:

1. an option to add custom names (not just numbers)
2. a tooltip over the buttons
3. to disable/enable just some of the buttons
4. pagination - meaning: use next, previous and "..." if there are too many pages

if the pagination had a template option (slot) that would of been perfect.

now i am wondering how is the best why to get my goal. is there a way to add templates to vuetify? is there a different component that has this options on the pagination?

Answer (score 0):

Read the api [here](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/paginations/) In answer to your questions:

1+2+3 This is not supported in vuetify out of the box and therefore you may want to consider writing your own pagination tool or looking for a different package.
4. This can be set in the props as described in the docs above, see `total-visible` prop and `length`.

Comment: thank you! but i need all 4 together. but i think i can manipulate vuetify tabs for this.